# Выдает ошибку: ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Если можно то по быстрее

```
def move_snowflake(snowflake):
    x,y=canva.coords(snowflake)
    canva.move(snowflake, 0,5)
    if y<600:
        window.after(50, move_snowflake, snowflake)
    else:
        canva.delete(snowflake)
        snowflakes.remove(snowflake)
        create_snowflake()
```

Comment: в приведённом коде такая ошибка может быть только в этой строке: `x,y=canva.coords(snowflake)`. Посмотрите, что возвращает `canva.coords(snowflake)`.

Comment: если `canva` - это tkinter'овский Canvas, то `coords(...)` возвращает четыре, а не два числа.

Comment: Добро пожаловать на  Stack Overflow на русском! Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («**почему этот код не работает?**») должны включать желаемое поведение, *конкретную проблему или ошибку* и *минимальный код* для её воспроизведения **прямо в вопросе**. Вопросы без **явного описания проблемы** бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).